# Adding and using header (HTTP) in nginx

Tags: http, nginx

I am using two system (both are Nginx load balancer and one act as backup).

I want to add and use few HTTP custom headers.

Below is my code for both:

```
upstream upstream0 {
    #list of upstream servers
    server backend:80;
    server backup_load_balancer:777 backup;
    #healthcheck
}

server {
    listen 80;
    #Add custom header about the port and protocol  (http or https)
    server_name _;

    location / {
        # is included since links are not allowed in the post
        proxy_pass "http://upstream0;"
    }
}
```

Backup system

```
server {
    listen 777;
    server_name _;
    #doing some other extra stuff
    #use port and protocol to direct
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

To add a header, add the [`add_header`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) declaration to either the `location` block or the `server` block:

```
server {
   add_header X-server-header "my server header content!";
   location /specific-location {
       add_header X-location-header "my specific-location header content!";
   }
}
```

An `add_header` declaration within a `location` block will override the *same* `add_header` declaration in the outer `server` block.
e.g. if `location` contained `add_header X-server-header ...` that would override the outer declaration for that path location.

Obviously, replace the values with what you want to add. And that's all there is to it.

Comment: the $http_HEADER and $send_http_HEADER variables allow accessing the contents of a headers in nginx see http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#Variables

Comment: Does `add_header` work when `proxy_pass` is used? This question seems to contradict it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14501047/how-to-add-a-response-header-on-nginx-when-using-proxy-pass

Comment: @cobaco This config adds this header into response header. is there any way to add in request header while sending it to proxy server ?

Comment: @IndraUprade Headers sent to the backend proxy server are managed with proxy_set_header: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header

Comment: @bd808 did not work for me

Comment: Also add `always` at the end to have it work for 400 codes

Comment: This inheritance will not work if there is already an `add_header` in the `location` block. In that case, the `add_header` in the `server` block seems to just be ignored.

Answer (score 15):

You can use upstream headers (named starting with $http_) and additional custom headers. For example:

```
add_header X-Upstream-01 $http_x_upstream_01;
add_header X-Hdr-01  txt01;
```

next, go to console and make request with user's header:

```
curl -H "X-Upstream-01: HEADER1" -I http://localhost:11443/
```

the response contains X-Hdr-01, seted by server and X-Upstream-01, seted by client:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Mon, 30 Nov 2015 23:54:30 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Hdr-01: txt01
X-Upstream-01: HEADER1
```