# How to catch NetworkError in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, referenceerror

In Chrome's JavaScript console, if I run this:

```
var that = new XMLHttpRequest();
that.open('GET', 'http://this_is_a_bad_url.com', false);
that.send();
```

I get an intentionally expected error:

```
NetworkError: A network error occurred.
```

I want to catch this, so I use:

```
var that = new XMLHttpRequest();
that.open('GET', 'http://this_is_a_bad_url.com', false);
try {
  that.send();
} catch(exception) {
  if(exception instanceof NetworkError) {
    console.log('There was a network error.');
  }
}
```

However, I get an error about NetworkError not being defined:

```
ReferenceError: NetworkError is not defined
```

How can I catch NetworkError?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think what you meant was:

```
if(exception.name == 'NetworkError'){
   console.log('There was a network error.');
}
```

I don't believe the Error is an instance of `NetworkError`, but thrown in this manner:

```
throw {
   name: 'NetworkError',
   message: 'A network error occurred.'
   // etc...
}
```

Comment: This works great.  I should also ask: In Chrome's JS console, it still shows "GET (url)" with a red X to the left of it while tallying the error on the bottom-right of the console.  Is there a way to catch this too?

Comment: Afaik chrome console shows all failed requests in this manner, catching the error will prevent breaking your code

Comment: In Firefox the name of the error is `TypeError` but the message says `NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource`

Answer (score 7):

I found this answer while looking for a way to examine a `Network Error` I got while using Axios, so if You are *not* using Axios, this answer is probably *not* for You.

The error object I receive through Axios has `config`, `request` and `response` attributes, and both the `request` and `response` have the `status` attribute. `response` object's attribute is displayed in the image below:

[image: error.response object from Axios]

My axios configuration looks like this:

```
this.client = axios.create(options);
this.client.interceptors.response.use(this.handleSuccessResponse, this.handleErrorResponse);
this.unauthorizedCallback = () => {};
```

and the `handleErrorResponse` method is:

```
handleErrorResponse(error) {
  // use the information from the error object here
}
```

---

EDIT: As suggested by [@Erdős-Bacon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8954541/erd%C5%91s-bacon):

If You are using axios and nginx, this might be the comment for You. I had issues with `error.response` being `undefined`, turned out it was because of CORS issue. Had to setup my nginx config to keyword always add appropriate headers to solve CORS, otherwise headers get stripped on error responses, so CORS issues crop up. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16308982) for more info.

Comment: FWIW, my axios network errors have a request status of 0, and the response object is undefined.

Comment: @DylanSmith are You sure You are checking in the right place? Or catching it the right way?

Comment: I think so.  The condition I'm working with is that the server is inaccessible (similar to the OP), so there is no response, so it makes sense that it would be undefined.

Comment: Well, that is a special case that You now know how to deal with :)

Comment: @DylanSmith Upvote. You're right. The answer is not suited for axios, cause `result.name` is always `"Error"` for me with axios errors. Checking if `result.response` is undefined is suited for checking network errors below layer 5. Also the result contains the boolean value `isAxiosError`.

Comment: If You are using axios and nginx, this might be the comment for You. I had issues with `error.response` being undefined, turned out it was because of CORS issue. Had to setup my nginx config to keyword `always` add appropriate headers to solve CORS, otherwise headers get stripped on error responses, so CORS issues crop up. See [this answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16308982).

Comment: When using Axios, you can also check if the "Network Error" is contained in error.toString(). error.toString() returns "Error: Network Error".

Answer (score 2):

With [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) I use the following code:

```
if (error.message === 'Network Error') {
   console.log('There was a network error.');
}
```

Comment: other answer suggests it should be `error.name` and not `.message`

Comment: @Mugen Yeah, but when I tested it only the official XMLHttpRequest provided error.name. With the axios package only error.message was provided. That's the reason for writing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [onreadystatechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/readystatechange) event.  You can get the status of the response.

Comment: readystate doesn't change until after send() is called, but the send() call is what's generating the exception.