# How to overwrite http Content-Disposition header in nginx.conf location block?

Tags: http, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nextcloud

I have a reverse proxy server that takes file from fileserver than sends them to user. I want to change filename before sending. I wrote a rule like below

```
location ~ downloads/(.*) {          
        proxy_pass         http://HOST:PORT/remote.php/dav/files/$1;
        add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; "filename=$args"';
   }
```

But when i send request i get this error;

```
ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION
```

Comment: Try [`proxy_ignore_header`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ignore_headers) directive.

Comment: i tried that command like this;
 `proxy_ignore_headers Content-Disposition;`
but nginx gives error
`nginx: [emerg] invalid value "Content-Disposition" in nginx: [emerg] invalid value "Content-Disposition" in /conf/nginx.conf:96`

Comment: Try [`proxy_hide_header`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_hide_header) one.

Answer (score 7):

Adding a header with `add_header` works well with proxy pass, but if there is an existing header value in the response it will stack the values.

If you want to replace a header value (for example replace this `Content-Disposition` then you will have to do this in two steps:

```
# 1. hide the Content-Disposition from the server response
proxy_hide_header Content-Disposition;
# 2. add a new Content-Disposition header with your changes
add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; "filename=$args"';
```

See my answer on a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55692346/1697459).

Comment: proxy_set_header works for that too and it looks like it's hidden from the response

Comment: @Semyon No, [according to the documentation `proxy_set_header` is for "redefining or appending fields to the request header"](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header). So it can be used for setting request headers, but not for setting response headers.

Comment: ah, right, my bad