# How to add a header that resolves CORS error in nginx api calling?

Tags: nginx, cors

I have two subdomain behind my nginx: **panel.example.ir** and **api.example.ir**
While I call **api.example.ir** from my panel **panel.example.ir**, I see an error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.example.ir/api/test/pre_sale_customer_project_view?offset=0&limit=5&order=created_at.desc' from origin 'https://panel.example.ir' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Also when I add `add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;` to my **api** nginx conf, I have another error as below!

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'panel.example.ir, *', but only one is allowed.
```

What can I do now?

Comment: Have you tried to use `add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin panel.example.ir;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe have a look at this post. With `add_header` you will stack the header values when you use it as proxy. In the post it's described how you could hide the original header to replace it with a given one from nginx.

[How to overwrite http Content-Disposition header in nginx.conf location block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70936785/how-to-overwrite-http-content-disposition-header-in-nginx-conf-location-block)

So in your case maybe use:

```
proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin panel.example.ir;
```

or you configure your application so it is always responding with the correct headers.