# Django Rest Framework Middleware Adds Strict-Transport-Security Header to All Responses Except OPTIONS Requests

Tags: django-rest-framework

I've encountered a bug in my Django Rest Framework project where a middleware adds the Strict-Transport-Security header to all responses, which solves an issue locally. However, after deployment, I noticed that the header is missing in OPTIONS requests. Can anyone suggest what might be causing this issue?

Here's the middleware code I'm using:

```
class AddStrictTransportSecurityHeaderMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        response['Strict-Transport-Security'] = 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains'
        return response
```

This middleware is added to the middleware list in settings.py.

Locally, when I make requests to my API endpoints, all responses include the Strict-Transport-Security header. However, after deployment, OPTIONS requests don't include this header. Other request types (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) have the header added correctly.

Is there anything specific about Django Rest Framework or middleware that could be causing OPTIONS requests to behave differently? Any insights or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`django-cors-headers`, which you are probably using, handles OPTIONS in it's middleware.

[django-cors-headers/middleware.py](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers/blob/4b4eb42f2d75529c318d9274a9562a40927b5005/src/corsheaders/middleware.py#L78):

```py
def check_preflight(self, request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponseBase | None:
        """
        Generate a response for CORS preflight requests.
        """
        request._cors_enabled = self.is_enabled(request)  # type: ignore [attr-defined]
        if (
            request._cors_enabled  # type: ignore [attr-defined]
            and request.method == "OPTIONS"
            and "access-control-request-method" in request.headers
        ):
            return HttpResponse(headers={"content-length": "0"})
        return None
```

Check `MIDDLEWARE` key in your `settings.py` file. `"corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware"` middleware is usually included near the beginning of the list. Middlewares are applied in order, so if your middleware is in the list after cors, it will never be reached.

Comment: so should I move my middleware to the top or override check_preflight of django-cors-headers ??

Comment: @AbdulRahman. If you really have to add header in django, I would move middleware just before corsheaders in the list. This may have unintended consequences though, so test the change a lot. Ideally I would rather handle adding Strict-Transport-Security outside of Django - you are probably serving your django app as reverse proxy behind some webserver (Apache, Nginx, Caddy, Traefik), which can handle headers.

Comment: @AbdulRahman. additionally I am unsure about why would you use Strict-Transport-Security with OPTIONS. OPTIONS is in practice more or less used just for cors, so corsheaders handling it alone should be fine. What benefit you get from adding Strict-Transport-Security to it?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I got a security bug from the testing team when they tested our app in burp suite. I am not sure why the Nginx did not handle the response header. Then it was probably the issue from infra team right ?

Comment: @AbdulRahman. nginx won't add this header by default, you need to use add_header in nginx config. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/16308982/6212530 For security reasons I believe that Strict-Transport-Security on GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, PATCH should be sufficient, are you sure your security team also wants it on OPTIONS?

Comment: Thank you for the response, can you please tell me why OPTIONS does not require the header so I can educate my testing team. From what I understood , during the preflight check the browser checks for the sts header. If the header is present then it will route all non https requests to https requests. If that is correct then OPTIONS should also have it right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257180/discussion-between-matija-sirk-and-abdul-rahman).