# How to block crosssite scripting in Azure App Servie?

Tags: azure, docker, xss, azure-web-app-service

I have nodejs docker application is running on Azure's App Services. It has been set up a custom domain.

I want to block cross-site scripting. In nginx i can add `more_set_headers "x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block";` to block the cross-site scripting.

How do we achieve this in Azure App Service? Is this okay to run Nginx in the same container?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set that header in his nginx.conf or default.conf.
Refer - [Adding and using header (HTTP) in nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973047/adding-and-using-header-http-in-nginx)

Node js can run inside a container without Nginx - in this case you can set the Header via code 2. If you want Nginx to act as a reverse proxy for his Node application..you have to build a custom container with both and then you can set the header via Nginx configuration

Comment: Hi @DashleenBhandari-MSFT How do we achieve this in Azure App Service? Nginx is not in the App Service.

Comment: 1. Node js can run inside a container without Nginx - in this case you can set the Header via code
2. If you want Nginx to act as a reverse proxy for his Node application..you have to build a custom container with both and then you can set the header via Nginx configuration

Comment: Thanks, @DashleenBhandari-MSFT! Makes sense to set up in the Node application. I thought Azure Web App Service may manage the headers like CORS