# How can I identify incoming requests from EKS LoadBalancer on app level?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-elb, amazon-eks

I have a k8s service defined as `type: LoadBalancer` which sets an external LB. Can I identify on application level that an incoming request is routed from the LoadBlancer?

Are there any guaranteed http headers? Can I define custom headers for that service that would be added to all incoming requests?

Comment: The headers it sets (x-forward-*) are commonly set by ingress controllers as well. Why both an ingress and a servicetype Loadbalancer? There is an ALB ingress that you can use

Comment: I would like to distinguish incoming requests: which are from the LB (currently defined by service only) and which are from an internal ingress

Comment: @jordanm - and regarding ALB, does it support all annotations of a regular LB? Or is it, like, ingress-controller?

Answer (score 1):

If your internal ingress is using nginx as an ingress controller you can [add a custom header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11973844/3833773) that will indicate that.

Comment: I might use that if I don't find another solution, but I'm  more interested in adding a custom header to requests from the LoadBalancer, if this is somehow possible.

Comment: Plus, I didn't get how to add this nginx snippet into an ingress config file (?)

Comment: This is an example for adding headers to an nginx ingress - https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/customization/custom-headers/. AFAIK there is no way to add custom headers to a request coming from elb, but you can ask open a support ticket for aws or ask in their developer forums.

Comment: Weird they do not support it out of the box. Anyways, meanwhile using your other suggestion with the internal ingress. תודה :)

Comment: No problem. I don't think it's weird BTW. A load balancer is not the same as a web server, and it makes sense for it to not cover this functionality

Answer (score 0):

[ELB guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/how-elastic-load-balancing-works.html) says that:

> Application Load Balancers and Classic Load Balancers add X-Forwarded-For, X-Forwarded-Proto, and X-Forwarded-Port headers to the request.

Have you already been trying using these ones?

Comment: I read this doc. Since I'm trying to distinguish a LoadBalancer and an ingress controller (which is also LB), then I don't think I can rely on these headers. I was hoping for something more uniq, or, the ability to add custom headers

Comment: @Kludge ,  am I right that Ingress handles traffic generated outside your VPC and 'LB Service' is used by hosts from vpc (basically EC2 instances) ?

Comment: no, the LB service actually acts as an external server. I would like to trace these incoming requests app-level